# Can't install module with python-pip properly

Tags: python, module, installation, pip

I would like to install a module but `pip` is not installing it in the right directory which I assume should be `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`. After all, I just installed Python 2.7.2 today. Originally I had 2.6.5 and had installed modules successfully there. So I think something is wrong with my Python path.

**How to have all my module installations go to the proper python2.7 directory?**

```
s3z@s3z-laptop:~$ pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/requests-0.6.1-py2.6.egg
Installing collected packages: requests
Successfully installed requests
s3z@s3z-laptop:~$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct  1 2011, 14:26:08) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named requests
>>> ^Z
[3]+  Stopped                 python
```

Also here is what my Python directories look like now http://pastie.org/2623543

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you installed Python 2.7, did you install the Python 2.7 version of easy_install and PIP? The existing installations are configured to use Python 2.6 by default which may be causing your issue.

Comment: I installed Python-PIP after installing Python 2.7.2. And yes, I did try installing with easy_install at first but quickly ran into troubles there too. I then re-installed setup tools w/ easy_install again which was placed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages but even then it did not work.

Comment: Ok I recompiled Python 2.7.2 from source, installed `python-setuptools`, did `sudo easy_install pip` and then `sudo pip install requests` worked fine.

Answer (score 5):

You are probably using `pip` linked to python2.6, instead of 2.7. If you have installed `pip` properly with python2.7, you can do:

```
pip-2.7 install requests
```

If not, try installing this way:

```
curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
[sudo] python2.7 distribute_setup.py
curl -O https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
[sudo] python2.7 get-pip.py
```